# Get matching names from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

My problem is, I have a database of people names and their achievements. Now, I have some paragraphs which contains the person names. I need to extract the names from those paragraphs. The web-end of the application will append a hyperlink of the extracted names with their activities.

Data in my database might look like:

```
Name          |  Achievement
----------------------------------------                              
Steve Jobs    |  Founder of Apple
Bill Gates    |  Founder of Microsoft
```

Now I have string like: `After saving up some money, Steve Jobs took off for India in the search of enlightenment.`

I need to find `Steve Jobs` from the above string and add to hyper link to that. 
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server really isn't the best place to do this, because a hyperlink is by definition HTML, but...

```
declare @s varchar(500) = 'After saving up some money, Steve Jobs took off for India in the search of enlightenment.'

select 
    @s = REPLACE(@s, name, '<a href="#">'+name+'</a>')    
from yourtable
where @s like '%'+name+'%'
select @s
```

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks. But my db size is very big. Is there any optimized way? or any better technology than SQL Server?

Comment: If you have verybig database  you can use SQL FULLTEXT Search  instead of like

Answer (score 0):

You should save your data in some pre defined format for example, you can use `***` at the start & end of `person name` like.

After saving up some money, `***Steve Jobs***` took off for India in the search of enlightenment.

Then you can extract the Person Names by finding `***` through sql

**EDIT:**

I myself will try to find some other way to do it. For example i will save the Person Names in separate columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I can't edit the string. That comes from news feed.

Comment: The names are in separate columns itself. See the post now.